# Accessing a Highmaps node from outside the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to build a mobile friendly Highmap where users can click on a node in the map and trigger a function that displays supplementary data in a separate div. I've got this part to work no problem!

However I'd like to add a feature that lets users select a node from a drop down list outside the map as the areas in the map are quite small and fiddly to access on a mobile device. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please provide live working example of your map.

Comment: Link is here: http://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ds-active-travel/index.html

Note that I'm using a compiler etc. so the js files aren't straightforward. When you select 'Go!' the map appears with a drop-down box on top of it. When the user selects an area on the dropdown box, I want the app to mimic the behaviour of clicking on an area of the map and reveal the charts.

Also any other advice on this gratefully received!

Answer (score 3):

You can find your point in `chart.series[0].points` array and then launch the same action as on `point.events.click`:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          this.select();
          printNodeName(this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
},

(...)

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    var point = chart.series[0].points.find((p) => p.name === 'Macedonia');
    printNodeName(point);
  });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/41y1y3qL/

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll be coding it up tomorrow so will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Worked a charm - thankyou! Although no good deed goes unpunished and I now have a new issue =( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191369/highmaps-ios-click-events-not-firing